# Possible unbalanced tuple when declaring multiple array

Tags: python

So I want to declare multiple array in 1 line but when I do that I get this warning "Possible unbalanced tuple"

I know it can be ignored but what is wrong? why when I declare these in separate line its OK but in 1 line I get this error?

```py
#get error:
arrayOne,arrayTwo = []
#not getting error: why?
arrayOne = []
arrayTwo = []
```

Thanks

Comment: the second argument is missing `arrayOne,arrayTwo = [],[]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't assigning `[]` to both names; you are trying to unpack exactly two items from `[]` and assign each one to a separate name. You can write

```
listOne, listTwo = [], []
```

but this is more clearly written as two lines

```
listOne = []
listTwo = []
```